# Odoo 15: How to check if current user is admin in view

Tags: view, odoo

I am working with approvals in Odoo and I am trying to replace `action_cancel` button.
This is my code currently:

```xml
<button name="action_cancel" string="Cancel" type="object"
                    attrs="{'invisible': &quot;['|','|','|',('request_status','in',['new','cancel']),'&amp;',('user_status','==',False),('has_access_to_request','==',False),'&amp;',('disable_cancellation','=',True),('request_status','=','approved'), ('request_owner_id', '!=', uid)]&quot;}"
                    data-hotkey="z" />
```

I also want to check if currently logged in user is admin. I have not found a way how to use environment method `.is_admin()`. Is there any way how to do this? I cannot use template directives and would like to avoid creating special field that will only check if the current user is admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_is_admin](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py#L927) function will check if the user id is equal to the `SUPERUSER_ID` or belongs to the `Administration/Access Rights` group

You can use `groups`attribute to restrict the button to admin users

***Example:***

```
groups="base.group_erp_manager"
```

Comment: The answer clearly shows how to use the `groups` attribute to restrict access to the button to administrator users, the example being there only to highlight the use of the `groups` attribute and the group to be used.

Comment: It could have benefitted from more context. It was not obvious to me as a beginner that "base.group_erp_manager" will perform an _is_admin() function check on the current user.  It almost sounded like you were proposing two different possible solutions.